# Resource with dynamic segment and retrieving the model in a nested route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have the following route :

```
@resource 'groups', {path: 'events/:event_id/groups'}, ->
  @route 'new'
```

In my new route, in order to build a new App.Group object, I need to know which is the event we're in.

So I have the following route, which corresponds to the resource :

```
App.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Event.find params.event_id
```

And the one which corresponds to the route :

```
App.GroupsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.store.createRecord App.Group
```

I would need to specify the group's event when creating it. However, in the GroupsNewRoute, I don't seem to be able to retrieve the event. The params don't include `event_id`.

How can I get the model from a parent resource in a route ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few different issues here:

You should not use `App.store`. The store should be available on routes as `this.get('store')`.

I'm not sure why you're naming your route `GroupsRoute`. Since it represents an event, you should name it `EventRoute`. This is not required, but it would be more idiomatic. Also, you don't need to specify the model for `GroupsRoute`. What you are doing is the default behavior.

Finally, you can get the model for another route via: `this.modelFor('groups')` in your route. That should solve your issue here.

Comment: GroupsRoute does not represent an event. It represent a list of groups, which are nested inside an event.